# React Native: Marker working statically but not dynamically

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm trying to showing multiple marker in React Native Mapview. My code

```
this.state = {
      coords: [
        { latitude: 23.759119, longitude: 90.411804 },
        { latitude: 23.759188, longitude: 90.41167 },
        { latitude: 23.759127, longitude: 90.41138 },
        { latitude: 23.759224, longitude: 90.411995 },
        { latitude: 23.7591, longitude: 90.41138 }
      ]}
```

It's working when code like as

```
<Marker coordinate={this.state.coords[0]} />
          <Marker coordinate={this.state.coords[1]} />
          <Marker coordinate={this.state.coords[2]} />
          <Marker coordinate={this.state.coords[3]} />
          <Marker coordinate={this.state.coords[4]} />
```

But not working when code like as

```
{this.state.coords.map((c, index) => {
            <Marker key={index} coordinate={c} />;
          })}
```

I didn't get any error. Also not understood why not working the codes. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. I've not returning anything. So modify the code like

```
{this.state.coords.map((c, index) => {
            return <Marker key={index} coordinate={c} />;
          })}
```